# insert multiple shortcodes within a shortcode wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am a new to php and would like to know how insert multiple shortcodes with shortcodes

the desired result would look something like this

```
[logo_section_2 section-title="1" section-title-text="WE SHARE THE SAME CULTURE" logos-second-row="true"]
  [logo_images logo-id="1" logo-image-source="http://localhost:8888/signal-theme-export/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/logo-swiss.png"]
  [logo_images logo-id="2" logo-image-source="http://localhost:8888/signal-theme-export/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/logo-hudson.png"]
  [logo_images logo-id="3" logo-image-source="http://localhost:8888/signal-theme-export/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/logo-twitter.png"]
  [logo_images logo-id="4" logo-image-source="http://localhost:8888/signal-theme-export/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/logo-index.png"]
  [logo_images logo-id="5" logo-image-source="http://localhost:8888/signal-theme-export/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/logo-reed.png"]
  [logo_images logo-id="6" logo-image-source="http://localhost:8888/signal-theme-export/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/logo-viagogo.png"]

  [logo_images_2 logo-id="4" logo-image-source="http://localhost:8888/signal-theme-export/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/logo-index.png"]
  [logo_images_2 logo-id="5" logo-image-source="http://localhost:8888/signal-theme-export/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/logo-reed.png"]
  [logo_images_2 logo-id="6" logo-image-source="http://localhost:8888/signal-theme-export/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/logo-viagogo.png"]
```

[/logo_section_2]

This is so I can add multiple rows of images

my php is as below

```
<?php
```

add_shortcode('logo_section_2', 'logo_section_2');
   function logo_section_2( $atts, $content = "" ) {
    shortcode_atts(
        array(
          'section-title' => false,
          'section-title-text' => '',
          'logos-second-row' => false,
          // .....
        ),$atts);

```
    $output = '';
    $output .= '<div class="logo-section clearfix">';   
      $output .= '<div class="logo-section--inner clearfix">'; 
          if ($atts['section-title'] == true) {
          $output .= '<h2 class="heading--small heading--bold heading--uppercase heading--sans-serif heading--center heading">'. $atts['section-title-text'] .'</h2>';
          } else {
                  $output .= '';
          }

          $output .=  '<div class="logo-section--row clearfix">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';

          if ($atts['logos-second-row'] == 'true') {
            $output .=  '<div class="logo-section--row clearfix">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
          } else {
                  $output .= '';
          }
      $output .= '</div>'; 
    $output .= '</div>';
  return $output;
```

}

```
add_shortcode('logo_images', 'logo_images');
function logo_images($atts){
  shortcode_atts(
    array(
      'logo-id' => '',
      'logo-image-source' => '',
      'logo-alt' => '',
    ),$atts);
    $output = '';
    if($atts['logo-id'] || $atts['logo-image-source']){
               $output .= '<img class="logo-'.$atts['logo-id'].'" src="' . $atts['logo-image-source'] . '" alt="" />';
    } else {
            $output .= '';
    }
    return $output;
 }
add_shortcode('logo_images_2', 'logo_images_2');
function logo_images_2($atts){
  shortcode_atts(
    array(
      'logo-id' => '',
      'logo-image-source' => '',
      'logo-alt' => '',
    ),$atts);
    $output = '';
    if($atts['logo-id'] || $atts['logo-image-source']){
               $output .= '<img class="logo-'.$atts['logo-id'].'" src="' . $atts['logo-image-source'] . '" alt="" />';
    } else {
            $output .= '';
    }
    return $output;
 }
```

any help would be awesome!

Comment: This looks too static code !

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is about nested shortcodes... you want to trigger a UI element that may have one or more (variable number) internal items.

This concept is difficult to explain because it requires several code concepts put together.  But I will try:

1. Outer Shortcode:

   a. Set a global to test if already in that shortcode

   b. call `do_shortcode($content)` to execute inner shortcodes

   c. (Inner shortcode will set up an global array)

   d. Generate full UI using a loop on the global array

   e. return the output
2. Inner Shortcode:

   a. set up a global array to be used by the outer shortcode

   b. generate the content and place the output in an array item

   c. return blank/no output

It's not that straight forward tho... you'll need to consider multiple outer shortcode calls, incorrectly nested shortcodes, and if you want or don't want non-shortcode in the inner layer to be processed or not.

Have a look at this [code](https://github.com/vinorodrigues/wp-bootstrap4/blob/master/plugins/inc/tabs.php)... maybe you can extract some ideas from it.

Comment: ( Link fixed. )